# NSSM Limit file size creation by day and keep last 10 days worth of logs

Tags: nssm

I want to use NSSM to capture a single days worth of std_out and I want to be able keep only the last 10 days worth of std_out logs. Is this possible? This is what I currently have.

```
nssm set app AppStdoutCreationDisposition 4
nssm set app AppRotateFiles 1
nssm set app AppRotateOnline 1
nssm set app AppRotateSeconds 86400
nssm set app AppRotateBytes 1048576
```